# Find mongo Database element from rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I has a form with name and password field.
I am using:
my 'users' collection consists of

> name and password keys

```
user = User.where({:name => params[:name]})
```

The above command is showing whether the name entered matches with the name in the database.But,I want to know the password of the same document and know whether it is same as entered password.

Answer (score 0):

`.where()` retrieves a set of results. You might want to access one of the fields to extract results, like:

`password = User.where({:name => params[:name]}).first.password`

Another idea would be to use the password to query the document like this:
`user = User.where({:name => params[:name], :password => params[:password]})`

Also, another thoguth: you should be securing your user's password, and not transfering over as plain text to store it in your database (sorry if this is not the case, just checking).

Comment: ,Is their anyway, without gems. authenticate user by using digest type on password instead of text type?

Comment: Every time i made a query using `User.where({:name => params[:name], :password => params[:password]})`.it is always passing the if statement
that is if i keep:
`if user` This code is always validating to true.I want to assign session using `session[:user_id] = user.id` .but,getting error 
_undefined error .id methods_